# Does Nix solve the DLL hell problem differently from other more popular package managers for Debian or Arch?

Tags: debian, arch-linux, package-management, nix

https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/introduction.html says about Nix that

> **Multiple versions**
>
> You can have multiple versions or variants of a package installed at
> the same time. This is especially important when different
> applications have dependencies on different versions of the same
> package — **it prevents the “DLL hell”. Because of the hashing scheme,
> different versions of a package end up in different paths in the Nix
> store, so they don’t interfere with each other.**
>
> An important consequence is that operations like upgrading or
> uninstalling an application cannot break other applications, since
> these operations never “destructively” update or delete files that are
> used by other packages.

Does Nix solve the DLL hell problem differently from other more popular package managers for Debian or Arch?

If yes, does Nix have advantages over them in terms of solving the DLL hell problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, that's kind of the whole point of Nix, and it's explained in detail in [Eelco Dolstra's thesis](https://edolstra.github.io/pubs/phd-thesis.pdf) which I recommend you read.

Other package managers in typical Linux distributions do not solve the DLL hell problem in a dependable way: they require constant attention from all the people maintaining packages.  For instance, they have to manually figure out what packages their package depends on and input that into the system.  When a user installs a new version of a library, that library will automatically get used by lots of previously-installed software and possibly break some of it.